# openssl SERVER HELLO gmt_unix_time is wrong

Tags: openssl

I have an error with openssl while TLS shaking hand.Like the picture 1 show, obviously the gmt_unix_time is wrong.
[image]

And i have another server that works all right, like the picture 2 shows.
[image]

My question is how to set the gmt_unix_time to the right state even or Not representable?

Comment: Oh,i have found some thing at here,but i can not kown what to do, can anybody see?http://www.ietf.org/mail-archive/web/tls/current/msg09861.html

Comment: It looks like both are random, but the top one got close to something that looked like a unix time. The latest trend is to abandon unix_time and use a purely random value. The time was supposed to help with a unique value in case of catastrophic PRNG failure.

Comment: Are you trying to do this in code? If so, I don't believe you can. I don't ever recall seeing an OpenSSL interface to control it (but I could be mistaken).

Comment: @jww Thank you for comment.I think this can be controled,as i have seen some one set the random file to /dev/random.

Answer (score 0):

I have dealing this by the function call SSL_CTX_set_session_cache_mode(global_sslctx, SSL_SESS_CACHE_OFF). Wish be help.